# ¿se puede hacer que el getmax de un arreglo de objetos sea una funcion?

Tags: javascript

tengo un template que tiene un type number que tiene la propiedad max
lo que quiero es transformar esta linea
**const GetMax = id => Productos.find(a=> a.id==id).cantidad_disponible;**
a una funcion para que me la pueda leer en el template

este es mi intento

```
  function GetMAX(id,valor){

      const GetMax = id => Productos.find(a=> a.id==id).cantidad_disponible;
    let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);

     document.getElementById("Q_"+id).innerText=GetMax(id)-valor;

      itemCarrito.cantidad=valor;
     // updateTotal(itemCarrito);
    }



    
 <input type="number" value="${cantidad}" id="PRE_${id}" max="GetMAX(${id},this.value" 
   min="0">
```

Comment: `const GetMax` ya es una función

Comment: Iba a decir lo mismo :p

Comment: Digamos que tienes esta función-> `function sumar(a,b){return a+b}`, puedes escribirla como `const sumar = function(a,b){return a+b}`, o `const sumar = (a,b)=> {return a+b}`, o `const sumar = (a,b)=> a+b`, son tas equivalentes